# solving fully parenthesized expressions with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am having trouble coming up with a recursive method that can solve fully parenthesized equations..such as `((3+2)/(1+4))`.  I was able to come up with a recursive solution for solving infix expressions like `+*+3421` using recursion, but for something like `((3+2)/(1+4))` I am a little stuck.

```
def evalPrefix(exp):
    it = iter(exp)
    return evalPrefixInner(it)

def evalPrefixInner(it):
    item = it.next()
    if isInt(item):
        return int(item)
    else: 
        operand1 = evalPrefixInner(it)
        operand2 = evalPrefixInner(it)
        return execute(item, operand1, operand2)
```

Comment: ((3+2)/(1+4)) -> (5/(1+4)) -> (5/5) -> 1 ... this is how I am imagining the breaking down of the recursion should go?

Comment: Glad to be of help.  BTW, I rolled back question to include your original prefix-based source, as form of my answer makes more sense with it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar is:

```
expr ::= int | ( expr op expr )
```

correct?

So, ignoring error checking, something like...

```
def evalExpr(it):
    item = it.next()
    if isInt(item):
        return int(item)
    else: 
        //item should = lparen
        operand1 = evalExpr(it)
        op = it.next()        
        operand2 = evalExpr(it)
        rparen = it.next() 
        return execute(op, operand1, operand2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`shunting-yard algorithm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) :

```
dic={"+": lambda x, y:x+y,
     "-": lambda x, y:x-y,
     "/": lambda x, y:x/y,
     "%": lambda x, y:x%y,
     "*": lambda x, y:x*y}

def algo(x, op=None, nums=None):
    if x != "":
        op = op if op else []
        nums = nums if nums else []
        item = x[0]
        if item in ("+","-","%","/","*"):
            op.append(item)
        if item.isdigit():
            nums.append(item)
        if item==")":
            operator = op.pop()
            opd1, opd2 = int(nums.pop()), int(nums.pop())
            ans = dic[operator](opd1, opd2)
            nums.append(ans)
        return algo(x[1:], op, nums)
    else:
        if op and nums:
            operator = op.pop()
            opd1, opd2 = int(nums.pop()), int(nums.pop())
            return dic[operator](opd1, opd2)
        else:
            return nums[-1]

print algo("((3+2)/(1+4))")  #output :1
print algo("((5+2)*3*(2+5))") #output :147
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the input for valid data and then use the [`compiler`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-compiler.html) module to parse the expression like so:

```
import compiler
expr = compiler.compile(r'((3+2)/(4+1))', 'err', 'eval')
```

and then you can use:

```
eval(expr)
```