# How to undo a string and calculate

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [parsing math expression in python and solving to find an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055884/parsing-math-expression-in-python-and-solving-to-find-an-answer)

How can I "undo" a string with plus and addition signs in order to calculate them?

I have a string for example:

> '6*1+7*1+1*7'

I tried int() but I've got error. How can I undo this whole string to just get a pure integer calculation?

Answer (score 3):

You have to actually implement the operations you want to support by parsing the string and calculating the result. A trivial parser would look like:

```
>>> import functools,operator
>>> sum(functools.reduce(operator.mul, map(int, summand.split('*')), 1)
...     for summand in '6*1+7*1+1*7'.split('+'))
20
```

Note that the built-in [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) may work in a one-off script or an interactive console, but it interprets the string as Python source and therefore allows anyone who controls the string (i.e. the user) to [execute arbitrary Python commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution).

Comment: a more complete implementation of this solution can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055884/parsing-math-expression-in-python-and-solving-to-find-an-answer

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks, didn't note that. The question should be closed as a duplicate then.

Comment: Thanks for that reference. How can I delete my post?

Comment: @Flow You don't. It will get closed automatically as soon as five people (with sufficient privileges) vote for it, and then serve as a [signpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) to help anyone else describing the same problem with similar words find the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

use [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
In [177]: eval('6*1+7*1+1*7')
Out[177]: 20
```

or `exec`:

```
In [188]: exec compile('6*1+7*1+1*7','None','single')
Out[188]: 20
```

Comment: Note that this is extremely dangerous with user-supplied input.

Comment: a safer solution can be found here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055884/parsing-math-expression-in-python-and-solving-to-find-an-answer

Comment: @JoranBeasley Even I tried something similar some time back : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13104488/846892.